# Users collection data does not display on aslagle reactive table

Tags: meteor

I have created some users and i have data in my users collection.I wan to display this data in a reactive table https://github.com/aslagle/reactive-table

This is my helper code

```
settings: function () {
        return {
            collection: Meteor.users.find(),
            rowsPerPage: 10,
            showFilter: true,
            fields: ['_id', 'profile.schoolname', 'profile.schoollocation']
        };
    },
```

and this is my html

```
{{> reactiveTable settings=settings}}
```

When i run the code,only the fields i have defined show but not the data.

What could be the problem?.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way.

In the helper

```
 settings: function () {
    return {
    collection: 'ma',
    rowsPerPage: 5,
    showFilter: true,
    showNavigation: 'auto',
    fields: [
        { key: '_id', label: 'Id' },
        { key: 'profile.schoolname', label: 'Name' },
        { key: 'profile.schooltelephonenumber', label: 'Telephone' },
        { key: 'profile.schoollocation', label: 'Location' }
    ],
    useFontAwesome: true,
    group: 'client'
};
},
```

and in my publish

```
ReactiveTable.publish("ma",
    function () {
            return Meteor.users;
    }
);
```

the html

```
{{> reactiveTable settings=settings}
```